# SIM5320A, device connected to 3G Network but can't ping server

Tags: arduino, gsm, 3g

I've been trying to make this `SIM5320A` module send `HTTP` requests to my server but even though it appears connected to the internet I can't seem to ping any server or make any requests.

I'm sending AT commands through a terminal on my Linux PC.

`AT+CPIN` appears `READY`

I've configured through the `AT+CGDCONT`, `AT+SOCKSETPN = 1` and `AT+CGSOCKCONT` commands, adding my service provider's APN.

`AT+NETOPEN` returns `OK`. Running it again returns `Network is already opened`.

`AT+CPSI`? show's that it's connected to the WCDMA network and is `online`.

`AT+IPADDR` throws a proper IPv4 address.

So I'm trying to do `AT+CPING="google.com"`,1 but it just won't connect.

I've even been able of sending a SMS and reading GPS coordinates, just failing in the internet stuff.

Am I missing any configuration steps? There is so little information online on this device.

Comment: Does AT+CPING give any kind of message back to you? It may not know how to resolve names. Not sure how it would know what DNS server to use unless you configure it. Not sure you can do that at the modem level. Maybe try a hard coded IP address first.

Comment: AT+CPING tries to ping 4 times and returns unsuccesful each time. According to the datasheet passing a domain name should be fine, but I'll try a hard coded IP address too.